# clustering observations in the same category together in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Using the following code I was able to create this graph

```
ggplot(data=dur)+geom_line(mapping=aes(x=Year,y=Country,color=dur$elec.sys.fam
+ ,size=1.1))+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
```

[image]

My Question is as follows

each of the countries ("Country") is associated with a geographic region under categorical variable ("Reg").

how do I cluster the countries together by regions? So those countries in the same region appear together

Here is a sample of my dataset

[image]

Comment: If you can provide an example dataset (that includes the countries and regions), I bet someone can give you a solution with factor ordering using the `forcats` package.

Comment: I thought of ordering too, but I think this should be possible within ggplot2 as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use `facet_wrap()` to faced by region and keep country on the categorical axis.

Comment: `ggplot(data=dur)+geom_line(x,mapping=aes(x=Year,y=Country,color=dur$elec.sys.fam
,size=1.1,by=dur$Reg))+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))+facet_wrap(~dur$Reg)`  I tried using this, but it says ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class integer

Comment: You don't need to reference your dataframe with `dur$` in `facet_wrap()` (or anywhere in your ggplot code), just your column.  `+ facet_wrap(~Reg)`